# cannot reach mapped li element inside of html collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have a small react search app where I search data and I put 5 data per page
I want to reach the li element's length (I mapped user names in an `li` tag in my Posts component)

However when I consoled log below code it is an empty array:

```
const el = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item")
console.log(el)
```

I tried to reach without mapping method, it works properly however since there is a mapping inside of the tag, it gives me an empty array.

How can I reach li element's length here?
Here is the console result:

[image: image of console output]

> *HTMLCollection {}*
> __proto__: HTMLCollection

Below is my code of my components

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Posts = ({ posts }) => {
  const [searchTerm,setSearchTerm]=useState([]);

  const el = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item")
  console.log(el)

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          placeholder="Type here..." 
          onChange={e => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button 
        type="submit"
        >
        Search
        </button>
      </div>
        <ul className='list-group mb-4'>
        {posts.filter(value => {
           if(searchTerm === ""){
              return value
            } else if(value.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toString().toLowerCase())){
               return value
              }
        }).map(post => (
          <li key={post.id} className='list-group-item'>
            {post.name}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

Comment: Why would you use `getElementsByClassName` in React.js?

Comment: What does s `post` look like exactly?

Comment: what should I use to reach ? I am a new react learner

Comment: it is like below;  5 names per page                                                                                                                  Hines Daniel
Cameron Norton
Carissa Hernandez
Melisa Workman
Wilcox Vaughn

Comment: @Ayse8888 i meant give us the code. It's obviously meant to be an object, but it's important to verify the object structure with the code you've written.

Comment: I changed this way but still the same. I used this because they wanted from me to show 5 datas per page when the page is loaded. however I also needed to use filter so that I can receive the name when I type a name in the input. I will also share my PostResults component codes partially since it is too long. The problem is I need to add load more and pagination functionality. I added both but I try to make the load button disappear when I clicked once so that the pagination comes under. That's I was trying to reach the li element. I was gonna make li.length > 5 ? display : none : display:block

Comment: import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Posts from './Posts'
import Pagination from './Pagination'


const PostResults = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [postsPerPage, setPostsPerPage] = useState(5);
  
  const loadMore = () => {
    setPostsPerPage(value => value + 5)
  }

  const getData = () => {
    fetch('data.json')
    .then(response => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(data => {
      setPosts(data)
      console.log(data)
    })
  }

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  },[])

  

  // Get current posts
  const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
  const currentPosts = posts.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);

  // Change page
  const paginate = pageNumber => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

Comment: return (
    <>
    <Posts posts={currentPosts} />
    <button 
      type="submit" 
      className="load"
      onClick={loadMore}
    >
      Load More
    </button>
    <Pagination
      postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
      totalPosts={posts.length}
      paginate={paginate}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default PostResults;

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing DOM element before rendering.

First, render the DOM Element then we can access so we use useEffect.
Like this :

```
 useEffect(()=>{
    const el = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item") 
    console.log(el)
  },[])
```

Comment: I also tried this way, but still gives me an empty array :(

Answer (score 0):

Lots of problems here.

1. You're comparing an array `searchTerm` to an empty string `''`, which will never work.
2. `.filter` returns a boolean, or a truthy/falsy value, implicitly symbolizing a boolean. So you should recall the 6 falsy values in JS, and verify you're not returning one of them. `null, undefined, 0, '', false, NaN`.
3. Because of these 2 problems, you're always returning `undefined` from your filter function which is a falsy value, which means, your map never iterates and you're getting your unexpected results.

**Fix 1**

```js
  const [searchTerm,setSearchTerm]=useState(''); // change 1
```

**Fix 2**

```js
posts.filter(value => {
           if(searchTerm === ""){
              return true        // change 2
            } else  if(value.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toString().toLowerCase())){
               return true       // change 3
              }
            return false;        // change 4
        }
```